# jQuery droppable mouseover propagation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two Div's, both of them defined as droppable item and can accept the same item.
both of the Div's are positioned absolute and sometime they can be one over each other, in this case, when i'm dragging an element over the top Div, it seems that the hidden Div accepts the drop.

I tried to put event.stopPropagation() in the Div mouseover, mouseleave, droppable.over events but it does nothing..

The relevant code is:

```
$('.myDraggable').draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) { },
    distance: 20,
    revert: 'invalid',
    appendTo: '.myStage',
    scroll: false,
    helper: 'clone',
    zIndex: 999999
});

$('.myDroppable').droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) { },
    drop: function (event, ui) { },
    activate: function (event, ui) { },
    deactivate: function (event, ui) { },
    accept: '.myDraggable'
});
```

Comment: Do your two absolutely positioned `<div>` elements have different `z-index`? Can you post the relevant parts of your code so we can see the options you pass to `draggable()` and to `droppable()`?

Comment: yeah.. they have different z-index...

Comment: $('.myDroppable').droppable({
                over: function (event, ui) {
                    
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {

                },
                activate: function (event, ui) {

                },
                deactivate: function (event, ui) {

                },
                accept: '.myDraggable'
            });

Comment: $('.myDraggable').draggable({
                start: function (event, ui) {

                },
                distance: 20,
                revert: 'invalid',
                appendTo: '.myStage',
                scroll: false,
                helper: 'clone',
                zIndex: 999999
            });

Answer (score 0):

I can propose some workaround for your problem. Make elements draggable when mouse is over the element using 'live' or 'delegate'. The code below is not D&D but you can easly port it to you project by replacing adding css class with making object draggable.

```
   <div id='mouse-over-wrapper'>
    <div id='div1' style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px; top:100px; left:50px; z-index:100;">
    </div>
    <div id='div2' style="position:absolute; width:500px; height:500px; top:300px; left:250px; z-index:100;">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mouse-over-wrapper div').live('mouseover', function () {
            $(this).addClass('blue');
        });
        $('#mouse-over-wrapper div').live('mouseout', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('blue');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "Make elements draggable when mouse is over the element"
if i will do that, i will not be able to drag my elements from the begining...